# Why is matplotlib's tight_layout changing my xticklabels?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Here is a minimal working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ex2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'values': {'2019-05-16': -0.4539503789160822,
  '2019-05-17': 0.17824705254564818,
  '2019-05-18': -0.8145004682381226,
  '2019-05-19': -0.16068367742158898,
  '2019-05-20': -0.14703503546059876,
  '2019-05-21': 0.4063766692521381,
  '2019-05-22': -0.9572965166800591,
  '2019-05-23': -0.7125760201598659,
  '2019-05-24': 0.5195104837966258,
  '2019-05-25': 0.5763244454664754,
  '2019-05-26': 0.7512143968738716,
  '2019-05-27': 0.9708304482205082,
  '2019-05-28': 0.910905683484745,
  '2019-05-29': -0.19652191338402258,
  '2019-05-30': -0.7913575644422205,
  '2019-05-31': 0.406385536323757,
  '2019-06-01': -0.9636746362006964,
  '2019-06-02': -0.6904113830684114,
  '2019-06-03': -0.4015962383225227}})
```

The following code works as expected:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ex2.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image: working as expected]

However, doing the exact thing but simply adding the `tight_layout` command breaks it in this strange way:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ex2.plot(ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: xticklabels are now incorrect]

This seems like a bug, but if not I'd appreciate figuring out what's going on.

I am using the following versions:

```
matplotlib version: 3.1.0
python version: 3.6.8
pandas version: 0.24.2
```

**EDIT**

Changing the index to `datetime` via:

```py
ex2.index = pd.to_datetime(ex2.index)
```

And then re-running the above two pieces of code gives (in this case) consistent results.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
ex2.plot(ax=ax)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: correct xticklabels]

Comment: For me code works fine all the time on Windows 10. Matplotlib version: 3.1.0, Python 3.7.2 64-bit / 3.7.3 32-bit.

Comment: This is [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22334), which goes way back to [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7612). It will be fixed in pandas 0.25. But I would anyways recommend plotting actual dates, not strings, unless you want those strings to be handled like categories "apple", "banana", "cherry" etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Maybe it isn't related? I have missing x labels with Pandas `0.23.4` and matplotlib `3.0.3`. But in mentioned above environments everything seems ok for me.

Comment: No, it's the same issue. From version 0.23 to 0.24 the labels got fixed, but that made  the issue just more apparent than before (see my comment on that thread). From 0.24 to 0.25 the positionning of the labels is fixed, but 0.25 isn't released yet afaik.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm not surprised that the labels might be off from reading those threads. However, I am still surprised that a correct plot would become incorrect simply by calling `tight_layout`. My understanding was that `tight_layout` only moved around the padding.

Comment: Ok, let me explain it: The issue is that strings are just fed into a `FixedFormatter` (this basically just tells "First tick is labelled bla, second is labelled blubb", etc); but no special ticker is used. This means the default ticker (locator) is active. This default locator decides upon the tick positions depending on several things, notably also on the size of the axes. So you have 4 ticks with 4 labels, all good. But then the size of the axes changes due to `tight_layout`. Now you still have 4 labels due to the fixed formatter, but the default locator gives you 8 ticks...

Comment: ...of those only the first 4 are labelled, because the fixed formatter does not have more labels available.